# how to set width of a table cell using razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to set width of a column in a View (ASP.MVC), by using the following code:

```
<table >
<tr>
    <th class="col1"></th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ref)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td class="col1">
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.DocumentsID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.DocumentsID }) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.DocumentsID })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ref)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Style sheet (Site.css) code is:

```
.col1 {
width: 500px;
}
```

But this code is not setting the width of the cell. Any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: did you include your stylesheet?

Comment: 1.try clean your browser cache 2.Inspect your column in browser via developer tools. Maybe this width is overwritten

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 `@model IEnumerable<PmisMVC.Document>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Show";
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` 

Yes I did.

Comment: @Disappointed I cleaned cache and inspected column in browser shows this: [link](http://postimg.org/image/r5an21kxp/)

Comment: @ConvertToInt32 As you can see in this [Image link](http://postimg.org/image/r5an21kxp/), I have included .css and it is being read by the page.

Comment: @RehanKhan From screenshot it looks like this column has already 500 px. Try to set 1000px and look whether this column is much longer than before.

Comment: @Disappointed Changed `width` to 1000px but no desired output. Attaching new width [Image](http://postimg.org/image/ipro2opkl/) for you to review.

Comment: @Disappointed I am trying to set `Edit`,`Details`,`Delete` Actions Methods to display on one line. This is why I was trying to set width of this column but as you can see in the [Image](http://postimg.org/image/ipro2opkl/), width is not being set and column is displaying `Edit`,`Details`,`Delete` on 3 lines.

Comment: I ma not strong in css but maybe your table has some width property ? And as result cells width cannot exceed it ?

Comment: @Disappointed No I searched in .css for the keyword `table` and there is no match which means table has no properties set anywhere in .css.